# how to dispose current window in javafx

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am creating an application in Javafx ..there 2 winodws  1st window is login and another window is register.. 
In 1st window there is a button called "register" when click on register button registration form is visible but the 1st window which is not closing .. can I get the code for close that window ?

Comment: Call [`window.hide()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#hide--)

Comment: @James_D after button click  function right?

Comment: Call it wherever it is you want to close the window.

Comment: @James_D i will try

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Dialog`, a `Dialog` blocks the underlying window until the user closes the dialog, which is what typically is used in login situations.

[image: Sample Dialog]

Roughly speaking the code for using a dialog is as follows:

```
 Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
 ....
 Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();

result.ifPresent(usernamePassword -> {
    System.out.println("Username=" + usernamePassword.getKey() + ", Password=" + usernamePassword.getValue());
});
```

A full example of this custom login dialog can be found at http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/